# How to isolate Vuetify global styles

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've started to use Vue.js with Vuetify within an old existing project. So I did not rewrite all frontend, I just imported Vue and replaced some parts.

And then I've noticed quite an unexpected behavior - Vuetify has global styles for common classes like `.title` and it effects the whole page, not only `Vue` part.

So, the questions is, how can I isolate vuetify styles inside Vue components?

---

**UPD**: As suggested @DigitalDrifter I tried to use `stylus` block-level import. So I removed

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

from `main.js` and created a new `.styl` file (which was imported instead css) with the following content:

```
.vuetify-styles
    @import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'
```

And then added this class to the root component: `<App class="vuetify-styles">`

**UPD2:** After that you can get bug related to `stylus` compilation. More about it -> https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4864

**UPD3:** less also works fine for me.

```
# vuetify-styles.less
.vuetify-styles {
  @import (less) '../../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
}
```

And then just import it in your `main.js`

```
import './vuetify-styles.less'
```

Comment: what you means with 'isolate'?

Comment: I mean create something like namespace for `vuetify.min.css`, root class for all styles from this and other vue-related styles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stylus supports [block level imports](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/import.html#block-level-import).

If you've got the following:

```
// bar.styl
.bar
  width 10px

// foo.styl
.foo
  @import 'bar.styl'
```

The end result will be:

```
.foo .bar {
  width: 10px;
}
```