# Preventing Vuetify with treeshaking from overriding Bootstrap3's classes?

Tags: css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuetify.js

I'm working on a migration of an app from jQuery/Bootstrap3 to Vue/Vuetify. The end goal is to do one small thing at a time, for example convert the Navbar to be it's own Vue app and then other widgets one at a time.

Since the navbar is global it loads on every page and that means that Vuetify is knocking many of the Bootstrap3 styles out (like `.row`, etc). I am **not** using Vuetify's `row`, `container` or anything like that - I am only using the components in the `vuetify.js` below. Everything else should still be styled by boostrap.

Is there anyway to prevent Vuetify styles from leaking in? I've setup Vuetify with tree shaking and I am only importing the Vuetify components I need like this in my `vuetify.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify, {
  VApp,
  VCheckbox,
  VRadio,
  VSelect,
  VSwitch,
} from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VCheckbox,
    VRadio,
    VSelect,
    VSwitch,
  },
});

const opts = {};

export default new Vuetify(opts);
```

Then I simply use `Vue.extend` to extend the NavbarApp:

```
const NavbarAppRoot = Vue.extend(NavbarApp);
```

And finally I pass it in to my `Navbar` app like this with everything else

```
new NavbarAppRoot({
  el: navbarAppRootEl,
  store,
  vuetify, // <-- this is the vuetify.js from above
  propsData: {
    lang: config.lang,
  },
  i18n,
});
```

No where in the code am I importing `vuetify.min.css`.

Here is a screenshot showing how Vuetify is overriding bootstrap:
[image: Screenshot of Vuetify's row class overriding bootstraps row class]

How can I prevent Vuetify's styles from overriding my bootstrap3 styles that I still need to work for the time being?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent vuetify from polluting global style scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068452/prevent-vuetify-from-polluting-global-style-scope)

Comment: @MichalLevý unfortunately no. The answer that mentions to do `theme: { disable: true }` does not work when I add that into my `vuetify.js`, and the other answer with two upvotes does not explain why I must install `npm i postcss-parent-selector -D` and add a `.wrapper` class around all of my Vue apps (mine are not in an `index.html`, rather they are in `.jsp`'s while the conversion to Vue happens) on the application

Comment: I know linked answers is not perfect but it is pretty good start - especially the [link to a GH issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8530#)

Comment: Why `postcss-parent-selector` ? Because both libraries use some global styles/classes with same names. In order to avoid the conflict, one of them (Vuetify in this case) must be altered to use parent selector ([Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)) so the classes have effect only to elements under some ancestor (`.wrapper`)

Comment: @MichalLevý thanks for the explanation, I did do some more reading after seeing your previous comment to the last and it looks like it fits my needs, I've been trying to get it working now but there are some other gotcha's in our codebase that need cleaning up before anything that relies on postcss will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution here is sadly the ugly solution. In this case you need to manually apply the same classes that bootstrap uses but somewhere in your styles **after** Vuetify has loaded.

To solve this I have some global `.scss` files that are loaded *after* Vuetify - I created a `vuetify-overrides.scss` that looks like this and uses all of Bootstrap's `container`, `row`, `col-*` classes, and so on. It's not the pretty solution, but it works and prevents your styles from getting screwed up.

**NOTE:** If you have changed any of the default variables for Bootstrap like the default padding, margin, grid, etc. then you will need to generate your own file like this by going into dev tools and manually copying the output you see there and remember that you'll lose the benefit of being able to easily adjust these variables unless you create some higher order CSS variables for this file!

```
.container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.row {
  display: inherit;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-12 {
  right: 100%;
}
.col-xs-pull-11 {
  right: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-10 {
  right: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-9 {
  right: 75%;
}
.col-xs-pull-8 {
  right: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-7 {
  right: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-6 {
  right: 50%;
}
.col-xs-pull-5 {
  right: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-4 {
  right: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-3 {
  right: 25%;
}
.col-xs-pull-2 {
  right: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-1 {
  right: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-0 {
  right: auto;
}
.col-xs-push-12 {
  left: 100%;
}
.col-xs-push-11 {
  left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-10 {
  left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-9 {
  left: 75%;
}
.col-xs-push-8 {
  left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-7 {
  left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-6 {
  left: 50%;
}
.col-xs-push-5 {
  left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-4 {
  left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-3 {
  left: 25%;
}
.col-xs-push-2 {
  left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-1 {
  left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-0 {
  left: auto;
}
.col-xs-offset-12 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
.col-xs-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
.col-xs-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.col-xs-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.col-xs-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-0 {
  margin-left: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-md-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```